# cross correlation reverse order

Tags: signal-processing, signal-theory

I have a quick question.

I was wondering about the order of cross correlation of two signals.
Suppose there are two correlated signals. \$y(t)\$ and \$e(t)\$.

Does the following expression hold?

\$R_{ye}(-1) = R_{ey}(1)\$

Which is equivalent to:

\$\bar{E}(y(t)e(t+1))=\bar{E}(e(t)y(t-1))\$

Thanks very much in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have this property for all cross-correlations as a cross-correlation is a convolution without rotating the second vector. This means if you swap the vectors of your cross-correlation, the result will be mirrored.

Comment: Glad to hear! ;)